# If statement doesn't work in Python

Tags: python, encoding, module, html-parsing

I try to write a script to crawl my site.
But I stuck to the line 15 at the "if statement"; It does not make a comparison.
I think it's an encoding problem, or contain other characters. I guess.
The document encoding is ANSI and the website is ISO-8859-15.

**HParser.py:**

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint
import urllib2

url = 'http://DOMAIN.TLD'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
the_page = response.read()

class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        tag = unicode(tag)
        tag = tag.strip()
        print "'",tag,"'"
        if tag == 'a':
            for attr in attrs:
                if 'src' == attr[0]:
                    print 'Link: ', attr[1]

    def handle_endtag(self, tag):
        pass

    def handle_data(self, data):
        pass

    def handle_comment(self, data):
        pass

    def handle_entityref(self, name):
        pass

    def handle_charref(self, name):
        pass

    def handle_decl(self, data):
        pass

parser = MyHTMLParser()
parser.feed(the_page)
```

Comment: Does it help to change the print statement to this: print 'tag:', repr(tag)

Comment: what does print "'",tag,"'" print out?  what about print tag == 'a'?

Comment: What do your `attrs` look like? If `attrs` is a list of strings, then `attr[0]` will always be the first letter (so it will never be the whole word `'src'`). But it's difficult to say much more without seeing how you're getting this diagnosis.

Comment: It print out, ' a '. With repr() it print out ' u'a' '. And with type() it is a str.

Comment: Just enter the debugger there. Add this line: "import pdb; pdb.set_trace()" at the place where you want to know what's going on and see for yourself

Comment: I have try with `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and it just print out `if tag == 'a':`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested your code a little using the stackoverflow main page as the url. Here are what I found:

1) `tag == 'a'` evaluates to True correctly when it is 'a'.

2) attr prints out tuple as you expected. For example:

```
('href', 'http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/')
('class', 'cc-wiki-link')
```

So what I think this means is that you just never have any tuple with the first element being 'src' . When I parse the main stackoverflow page, I didn't get any tuple attr with attr[0] being 'src' either.

In short, the problem is with the if condition on line 18.

Now, I don't know html well enough to know if the 'src' attribute ever goes with the `<a>` tag, but I usually see 'src' with `<img>` tag, and 'href' with the `<a>` tag. So you may want to change line 18 to if `attr[0] == 'href'` instead.

Comment: So it works for you?; it's `if tag == 'a':` there is broken. I do have links on the page, and `print "'",tag,"'"` print our an a (link).

Comment: What url did you run your code on?

I may have misunderstood your question.

Comment: You have not misunderstood the question, but I think it is time that I go to bed. Apologies to all that I have disturbed with such a small problem.

Comment: See http://w3fools.com/ for an explanation why w3schools should never be referred. Quick summary: w3schools sounds like it has something with w3c, but they are completely unconnected + there is a big bunch of examples of wrong or misleading information.

Comment: Okay. I removed reference to w3schools.